# how to parse multi-line in a clean way using python?

Tags: python, string, string-parsing

As an example of the type of content I have to parse off of a ticket:

```
Name:
snakeoil
Host:
foobar

{block}
  email: some data here
  url: http://foo
  date: 01/02/16
{block}
```

I can identify the 'key', which is any word typically ending in a colon

I could use the regex module to do a match like `^\w$` to extract the key, but I must handle both the case where the value is in the same line vs in the subsequent line.

Having to fetch the word in the next line is what I can't think of how to address cleanly and/or effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You need `email`, `url` and `date` too:

```
>>> re.findall('\s*(.*?):[\n\s]?(.*)$', s, re.MULTILINE)
[('Name', 'snakeoil'), ('Host', 'foobar'), ('email', 'some data here'), ('url', 'http://foo'), ('date', '01/02/16')]
```

if not, @QiangJin solution is good

Answer (score 2):

You can still use regex if it's well formed,

```
>>> re.findall('(.*?):\n(.*)$', content, re.MULTILINE)
[('Name', 'snakeoil'), ('Host', 'foobar')]
```

Comment: To get both the multilines and on-same-line, I guess the regexp should be more like `r'(\w*?):\n?(.*)$'` ?

Comment: The regex from @DainDwarf does it. Thanks!